# repeating alarm not cancelling

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

I have a repeating alarm set, my problem is that after cancelling it doesn't cancel (I'm checking this with Log.v()

This is how I create the alarm (in an IntentService)

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intentToFire = new Intent(CAlarmReceiver.ACTION_CHECK_ALARM);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentToFire, 0);

private void rescheduleAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, TIME_TO_REFRESH);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), CHECK_TIME,   alarmIntent);
```

}

Then in an Activity I have a button on upon it's click it calls this code

```
private OnClickListener btnCloseApplicationListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intentToCancel = new Intent(CAlarmReceiver.ACTION_CHECK_ALARM);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0, intentToCancel, 0);
        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
        finish();
    }
};
```

After the finish() is executed I keep seeing the logs I have in DDMS window.
How can I cancel it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using same context for the intent. 
The intents have to match and I think your problem is that you are using different context when trying to cancel the alarm.

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentToCancel, 0);
```

Comment: Tapirboy, I though only the intent should match, Do you say I should instantiate the class I've used to create the alarm in this class in order to have the same context and then send that object as first parameter of getBroadcast?
Something like:
            intentToCancel = new Intent(CAlarmReceiver.ACTION_CHECK_ALARM);
            **PreviousClass c = new PreviousClass();**
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(**c**, 0, intentToCancel, 0);
            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
            finish();

Comment: No, you don't need to instantiate the class.

Comment: Yes, but I was rescheduling the alarm in a receiver, so I created a variable at application level and if that variable is false I just don't reschedule the alarm. Don't know what the cancel method didn't work.